# How to increase OCR accuracy in Node JS and Tesseract.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ocr

I use **tesseract.js** for detecting numbers in Node JS.
For example this is my image :

[image]

I run my script and it detects something like this:

*289 ,0*

And due to noises in the image, it considers *space*, other signs like *comma* and etc.

Is there anyway I can specify **just** numbers and no others signs like *space* and *commas*?

Also this is my code:

```js
tesseract.recognize(
    __dirname + '/Captcha.png',
    'eng',
    { logger: m => console.log(m) }
).then(({ data: { text } }) => {
    console.log(text);
});
```

Comment: I've tried that same image and I get `289 0` without `,`.

Comment: If you only want to return the numbers, you could filter the text and remove punctuation from the end result, but this is not improving the accuracy of OCR.

Comment: @NenadVracar Please notice **For example** statement.

Comment: @Kay Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't no the js tesseract API, however it seems that there is a quite simple work-around here by filter afterward:

```js
tesseract.recognize(
    __dirname + '/Captcha.png',
    'eng',
    { logger: m => console.log(m) }
).then(({ data: { text } }) => {
    const filteredText = Array.from(text.matchAll(/\d/g)).join("")
    console.log(filteredText)
})
```

Here's the test for just the filtering function:

```js
if (Array.from("209, 1".matchAll(/\d/g)).join("") !== "2091") {
  throw("Not working")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just started learning the inners of tesseract.js for an assignment.

API documentation explains how you may achieve what you want with the use of some parameters when lunching the job: **tessedit_char_whitelist** (setting white list characters makes the result only contains these characters) **preserve_interword_spaces** (keeps the space between words)
From https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/blob/master/docs/examples.md

```
const { createWorker } = require('tesseract.js'); 
const worker = createWorker();

(async () => {
  await worker.load();
  await worker.loadLanguage('eng');
  await worker.initialize('eng');
  await worker.setParameters({
    tessedit_char_whitelist: '0123456789',
    preserve_interword_spaces: '0',
  });
  const { data: { text } } = await worker.recognize('https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/img/eng_bw.png');
  console.log(text);
  await worker.terminate();
})();
```